# Db2 select sub queries

Tags: postgresql, db2

I want the same result in DB2 as the below query gives in posrgresql.

```
select ((select count(distinct gs_sender_id) from AMERISOURCEPROTOTYPE.transactions)
+ (select count(distinct gs_receiver_id) from AMERISOURCEPROTOTYPE.transactions)) as partners
```

The above query gives the sum of the 2 sub queries as partners . 
How can I do the same in DB2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select partners
from
(
values
  (select count(distinct gs_sender_id)   from AMERISOURCEPROTOTYPE.transactions)
+ (select count(distinct gs_receiver_id) from AMERISOURCEPROTOTYPE.transactions)
) t (partners);
```

But the following equivalent should be better from the performance perspective:

```
select 
  count(distinct gs_sender_id)
+ count(distinct gs_receiver_id) as partners
from AMERISOURCEPROTOTYPE.transactions;
```